# Artifactory Installation on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, bash

I have been trying to install [Artifactory OSS](https://jfrog.com/open-source/) on my new Raspberry Pi 4 (raspbian), but no luck so far. I tried all the following ways as suggested [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory) but nothing worked.

- Archive Installation
- Docker
- Docker Compose
- Debian

For example, [Archive Installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-LinuxArchiveInstallation) fails with below error.

```
2020-06-02T10:18:26.013Z [shell] [WARN ] [] [installerCommon.sh:610] 
[main] - Unable to execute yaml parser "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/../third-party/yq/yq -V",
 the executable might be corrupted or might not be compatible on the current operating system. 
(yq is used by installer to work with system.yaml)
```

I was able to get it working by running docker container with [this image](https://github.com/gordonforce/rpi-artifactory-oss). However, that image hasn't been updated recently and using an older version of artifactory. If my OS or Processor architecture is the problem, then the above image shouldn't work either.

Appreciate any help from fellow Raspberry Pi users.

OS - `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`

Comment: You need an image that is explicitly for ARM based machines; if it doesn't say that, then it isn't.  In addition, for full normal functionality you'll need to swap in the RPi kernel (I'm assuming Artifactory is linux based).

Comment: The more links do you use to understand your question, the more you risk to get ignored.

Comment: @Ingo you may be right... but I am not sure how else I can add that information to the question. I will try to just copy/paste information from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a docker image for this and the image can be found here
https://hub.docker.com/r/spagolu9/artifactory-oss-raspberrypi

Comment: not working for me on raspberry pi 4b. getting `docker run -it -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 --name artifactory spagolu9/artifactory-oss-raspberrypi
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested`

Answer (score 2):

**Generic Archive Installation** worked for me in **Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB**. Actually I wanna install **JFrog Artifactory Cpp CE** for **Conan** repository support. It's very straight forward. Where there was the only issue is **Java PermGen Memory Space**. As **Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB** runs on lower memory. Where I have to replace the line number 15 of `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/bin/artifactory.default` to change `-Xmx4g` by `-Xmx2g` as following:

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\""
```

---

```
sudo su
mkdir /opt/jfrog
export JFROG_HOME=/opt/jfrog; cd $JFROG_HOME
wget https://bintray.com/artifact/download/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-6.23.3.zip -O artifactory.zip
unzip artifactory.zip; mv artifactory-cpp-ce-6.23.3 artifactory; rm -rf artifactory.zip
```

---

```
# nano $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/bin/artifactory.default
# to replace the line number 15 to change -Xmx4g by -Xmx2g
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\""
```

---

```
$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/bin/installService.sh
# init 6

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start artifactory
systemctl status artifactory
tail -f $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/logs/catalina/catalina.out
```

It's clearly defined by [Sateesh](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/120519) in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sateesh-pagolu/artifactory-oss-raspberrypi/blob/master/Dockerfile). Actually I replied it again for the fresher **Raspberry Pi** enthusiastic those wanna implement it easily. [jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.12.2.zip](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.12.2.zip) takes lower memory. You can use it if memory is an issue. Both version worked fine for me.